# Matlab App designer: No public property [x] exists

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I'm playing around with Matlab's App designer, which seems to be a better dev tool than GUIDE in many aspects. After placing several components down and a bit of coding, I decided to add one more component and Matlab complains about it.

For example, do nothing but only add a `label` component and run the app, it returns:

> ```
> No public property Label3 exists for class UTPPP.
> Error in UTPPP (line 188)
>         createComponents(app)
> ```

The error mark is placed at line 177:

```
% App initialization and construction
methods (Access = private)

    % Create UIFigure and components
    function createComponents(app)

        % Create UIFigure
        app.UIFigure = uifigure;

        ......

        % Create Label3
        app.Label3 = uilabel(app.Tab); %<-----------Line 177
        app.Label3.Position = [892 547 31 15];
        app.Label3.Text = 'I''m the newly added label';
    end
end
```

Clearly, a property of `Label3` exists:

```
% Properties that correspond to app components
properties (Access = public)
    UIFigure               matlab.ui.Figure             % Ultrasonic pr...

    ......

    Label3                 matlab.ui.control.Label      % I'm the newly...
end
```

A similar error message is shown for whatever component I'd like to place down. Removing the component also removes such error message.

Has anyone run into this kind of problem? I don't know what I could have possibly done wrong; it could be a bug. I'm using Matlab R2016a.

Here is a screenshot of the app:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Matlab 2016a. After a restart, the app runs without error. I hope this is fixed in Matlab 2017a...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since no one has come up with an answer...

This is a bug in MATLAB 2016a. The cause of the bug is unknown and I don't know how to replicate it even though it happened to me multiple times.

---

The solution is quite simple:

**Restart the MATLAB.**